# Qt Installer Framework: TypeError cannot read property name

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-installer, qtscript

I tried creating an installer following the tutorial. I then added a script called "installerscript.qs" as per the startmenu example in the Qt Installer Framework directory.

The "installscript.qs" is as follows:

```
/****************************************************************************
**
**
** $QT_BEGIN_LICENSE:GPL-EXCEPT$
** 
**
**  open-editor to use.
**  Copyright (C) 2018  os_sys-devlopment-group
**
**  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
**  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
**  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
**  (at your option) any later version.
**  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
**  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
**  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
**  GNU General Public License for more details.
**
**  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
**  along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
** view the full license at https://www.stranica.nl/open-editor/license.txt
**
** $QT_END_LICENSE$
**
****************************************************************************/

function Component()
{
    // default constructor
}

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{

    component.createOperations();


    if (systemInfo.productType === "windows") {
        component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/customtexteditor.exe", "@StartMenuDir@/open-editor.lnk",
            "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@","iconPath=%TargetDir%/Logo.ico");
        component.addOperation("CreateDesktopShortcut", "@TargetDir@/customtexteditor.exe", "@DesktopDir@/open-editor.lnk", 
            "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@", "iconPath=%TargetDir%/Logo.ico",);
    }
    
}
```

My package.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    <DisplayName>open-editor</DisplayName>
    <Description>open-editor</Description>
    <Version>1.0.2</Version>
    <ReleaseDate>2019-11-10</ReleaseDate>
    <Default>true</Default>
    <Name>open-editor</Name>
    <Licenses>
        <License name="End User License Agreement" file="license.txt" />
    </Licenses>
    <ForcedInstallation>true</ForcedInstallation>
    <Script>installscript.qs</Script>
</Package>
```

When I execute the installer I get the error message:

```
Exception while loading component script "D:\system\temp\remoterepo-Q2Q7ZU\open-editor\installscript.qs": TypeError: cannot read property 'name' of null on line number: 1
```

This example worked when I tried it in the example directory. But gives me the above error when I modify it slightly to work with my own code.

any ideas why it does not work?

i use this command for binary creator:

```
..\..\bin\binarycreator.exe --online-only -c config\config.xml -p packages installer.exe
```

you can follow the following link to view the whole project: https://ftp.stranica.nl/index/help/project you can find all the files of my project

> the zip file in that dictory has the whole package in it
>
> i did changes to my whole packages so now everything looks a bit different but is the same

Comment: Can we see more about how you're setting this up and especially the `binarycreator` command line? From what you've posted, I don't see any issue. But I wonder where it's getting the path `com.mycompany.program` from. IIRC the packages path is set with `-p` option and an optional list of packages within that folder with `-l`. Are you using absolute or relative paths to specify the various locations? (Not sure that matters but maybe.)

Comment: see edit for the binary creator command

Comment: @MaximPaperno ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution

`open-editor` as packages name is wrong 
they want something like this:

`org.<vendor>.<name>.installer`

so if you rename `open-editor` to `org.devgroup.open_editor.installer` you will get a working online and offline installer

**edit:**

at least on windows this is the case

Answer (score 5):

As the other comment pointed out, the paths are important.

The QtInstallerFramework honestly doesn't have very good documentation and a lot of this I figured out by trial and error.

This is by no means the only way to do this.  Hopefully this helps as an example.  It is also worth noting that this will work on Linux/OSX as well with some slight variations.

Directory Tree:

```
rootdir
    installer
        config
            config.xml   <#1 below>
        packages
        com.<vendor>.installer
            meta
                package.xml  <#2 below>
        com.<vendor>.<name>  [This can be 1-N of these]
            meta
                installscript.qs  <#3 below>
                package.xml       <#4 below>
            data
                <name>
                    <executable and dependencies here>
```

config.xml #1:

Note: The @var@ are automatically substituted, fill in the stuff in []

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>[Name]</Name>
    <Version>[Version]</Version>
    <Title>[Application Title]</Title>
    <Publisher>[Publisher]</Publisher>
    <StartMenuDir>[VendorName]/[Name] [Version]</StartMenuDir>
    <TargetDir>@ApplicationsDir@/[Publisher]/[Name] @Version@</TargetDir>
    <ProductUrl>[yoururlhere.com]</ProductUrl>
</Installer>
```

package.xml #2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    <DisplayName>Installer</DisplayName>
    <Description>[Publisher] Software Installer</Description>
    <Version>[1.0.0]</Version>
    <ReleaseDate>[2019-11-13]</ReleaseDate>
    <Name>com.[Vendor].installer</Name>
    <Virtual>true</Virtual>
    <UpdateText>This changed compared to the last release</UpdateText>
</Package>
```

installscript.qs #3:

```
function Component()
{
    // default constructor
}

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    // This actually installs the files
    component.createOperations();

    if (systemInfo.productType == "windows") {
        // Start menu shortcut
        component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", 
                               "@TargetDir@/[Name]/[Executable.exe]", 
                               "@StartMenuDir@/[Name].lnk", 
                               "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@/[Name]", 
                               "iconPath=@TargetDir@/[Name]/[Name].ico");

       // Desktop Shortcut
       component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", 
                              "@TargetDir@/[Name]/[Executable.exe]",
                              "@DesktopDir@/[Name] @Version@.lnk",
                              "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@/[Name]", 
                              "iconPath=@TargetDir@/[Name]/[Name].ico");
    }
}
```

package.xml #4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    <DisplayName>[Name]</DisplayName>
    <Description>[Some description]</Description>
    <Version>[Version]</Version>
    <ReleaseDate>[Date]</ReleaseDate>
    <Name>com.[vendor].[name]</Name>
    <Script>installscript.qs</Script>
    <Default>false</Default>
    <ForcedInstallation>true</ForcedInstallation>
</Package>
```

From here you build your app, copy the binary to the com.[vendor].[name]/data/[name]/ folder.

If this is a Qt application you then should use the windeployqt.exe against each app in each respective the target directory ([name]/data/[name]/[executable.exe] to add in all the Qt dependencies.

Finally to make the installer package (offline version) with the following command (from the rootdir shown in the tree):

```
binarycreator.exe --offline-only -c "installer/config/config.xml" -p "installer/packages" "$[Name]Installer_[version].exe"
```

Comment: sorry but that is a typo in the question the file name is installscript.qs

Comment: cant i make a online installer with it?

Comment: becuse the whole point is that i want to make a online installer and in the example they use a online installer

Comment: I Assume this is the example you have been following? 
 https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qt-installer-framework-online-example.html

Comment: Your original post didn't include the online/offline bit, That said the differences are minimal, you also use the repogen tool for that, and as you pointed out in your revised post, pass the --online-only vs offline-only

Comment: hogen yes it is that example

Comment: I'll look at your repo online tonight and see if I can get it working and update this if so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202384/discussion-between-lua-and-dan-hogan).

Comment: and did you find the problem?